# VS2008-VS98 C++ cross debugging, some variables not recognized, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdb-files

I know this is considered an out-dated question, but I'm just curious about it.

Build a simple C++ program setmode.exe(From the book *Inside DirectX*, MS Press 1998) with Visual C++ 6 SP6(VS98) with `/Od /Zi`, then load this setmode.exe into Visual Studio 2008 debugger(on the same Windows XP machine that runs VC6 compiler), I find that

- Stepping through source lines works well.
- Call stack is displayed well.
- View variable values does **NOT** work well. Only some variables is recognized, many are not.

Then what is the reason for missing variable in VS2008? Any workaround(assuming I do not have the complete source code of setmode.exe to rebuild it with VS2008)?

See my screen shot to know it vividly.

[image: Visual C++ 6]

[image: Visual Studio 2008]